# Hook to main query with filters based on custom fields

Tags: loop

I would like to do a filter that will hook to the main query and filter all the posts by some given taxonomy terms or custom fields. For now I have made the custom filters for the $query to only select the posts that have a custom value for certain taxonomy as follows:

```
foreach($data as $taxonomy => $terms):
    $query->set($taxonomy,$terms);
endforeach;
```

and this solves it. But for example, I am having the following issue: I don't see how to provide instead of a taxonomy field, a custom field that has the value in a range; For example price is between 500-1000; where price is a custom field.

I have tried anything I could and searched a lot on the codex but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the format of a [`meta_query` in `WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

```
$meta_query = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'price',
        'value' => array( 500, 1000 ),
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    )
);

$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
```

Comment: I see. I have checked this now and it seems that after I do th $query->set('meta_query',$meta_query); it seems that by doing a var_dump() on the main query, the 'meta_query' field is set to bool(false); Why' that?

Comment: sorry, typo - `$meta_query => array(` should have been `$meta_query = array(` on the first line.

Comment: Yes. I know, I have fixed that. There is no problem. Also, to enable meta_query you have to do this: $query->meta_query = true; so the query will actually use the filters provided! And THANK YOU for explaining me this.. it solved my problem! BIG UP